# Change date format in Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have data with dates in columns as seen below. Dates are the headers

2020-04-14  2020-04-15  4/16/20

I would like to change 4/16/20 to read as 2020-04-16

I used:

df.loc[24,"4/16/20"] = "2020-04-16"
df

It ended up changing everything in the column and not the header
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strftime` to fix timestamp

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'col1': [1, 2, 3],
        'col2': [4, 5, 6],
        'col3': [7, 8, 9]}

# create headers
header = ['2020-04-14', '2020-04-15', '4/16/20']

# creating dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
#print(df)
#converting headers to datetime format
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
#fixing the datetime format
df.columns = df.columns.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand what you mean by `read as 2020-04-16`. Here's my solution. Hope it helps.

```
from datetime import datetime

# Parse the original date string using datetime.strptime
original_date = datetime.strptime("4/16/20", "%m/%d/%y")

# Convert the date to the desired format using datetime.strftime
new_date = original_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

print(new_date)
```

Output: "2020-04-16"

Answer (score 0):

According to [Pandas manual](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), you can use build-in `pd.to_datetime` with `infer_datetime_format` parameter.
Usually datatime format is the way to go.

Since your dates are already headers, all you need to do is just to convert columns to datatime:

```python
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, infer_datetime_format=True)
```

It will be in `%Y-%m-%d` format by default.